# How to stream a file.avi over network using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, avi, gst-launch

I'm trying to use gstreamer to send a sample file .avi over a network. The code that I'm using  to build my pipeline is the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin latency=200 \
filesrc location=filesrc location=/home/enry/drop.avi ! decodebin name=dec \
dec. ! queue ! x264enc byte-stream=false bitrate=300 ! rtph264pay ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5000 host=127.0.0.1 ts-offset=0 name=vrtpsink \
rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5001 host=127.0.0.1 sync=false async=false \
name=vrtcpsink udpsrc port=5005 name=vrtpsrc ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0
```

When I try to execute this command I'm getting this error:

```
gstavidemux.c(5383): gst_avi_demux_loop ():
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:dec/GstAviDemux:avidemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked
Execution ended after 0:00:00.032906515
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need a demux element before the decodebin, since an avi file would consist both an audio and video but you are using just one decodebin to decode them.

Take a look at the avidemux element [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-avidemux.html). You need it to get the video stream from the file.